# Rails get time in HH:MM AM/PM

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I have PHP code converting time to HH:MM format

`date("g:i a", strtotime('2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC')`

I want to convert same function in Rails.

I tried `DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC').strftime("%I:%M %p")`

which is showing error : no implicit conversion of time into string

Comment: i got the result.. no  error.. `DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC').strftime("%I:%M %p")
=> "07:00 AM"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eproduced the error :

```
DateTime.parse(Time.now).strftime("%I:%M %p")
# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Time into String
```

This is because `parse` methods accept only `String` objects, not any other objects. But it is `Time` object in your case. What you have to do is :

```
DateTime.parse(time_object.to_s).strftime("%I:%M %p")
# or directly
time_object.strftime("%I:%M %p")
```